# Cannot Restart Windows 10 workstation

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, reboot

I have a Windows 10 Pro (version 20H2) workstation that is joined to an Active Directory environment and it will not restart.

I first noticed that it would not restart when remotely attempting this command from another workstation (to which I was logged in as the domain admin):

```
@start /b cmd /c shutdown -r -f -t 60 -m \\computerName
```

Then, I logged into the workstation remotely (via RDP) as the domain admin and tried to restart using the Windows 10 start menu. Nothing happened.

Then I opened up an command prompt and typed:

```
shutdown -r -f
```

That command outputted:

```
The specified procedure could not be found.(127)
```

Lastly, I had the user try to reboot the workstation. Again, upon selecting "Restart" from the Windows start menu, nothing happens. So, this issue isn't exclusively a remote problem. It persist during physical access.

Even after powering off this computer, by removing electricity, the inability to reboot persists. It boots up and works fine, but it ignores all attempts to reboot it.

I will not have physical access to this computer until Monday, so I hoping someone has a solution that I can perform remotely.

Comment: Make sure it is OFF.   Hold down the Shift Key, power on, and then it should start in Safe Mode.  Make sure you select Safe Mode with Networking. Does it start?  Try to repair what was not working.

Comment: This workstation boots fine from a powered off state; it just doesn't reboot.

Comment: Run DISM / SFC from an Admin Command Prompt.  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  SFC /SCANNOW   .  Attempt to restart or shut down and start up.

Comment: @LonnieBest - "The specified procedure could not be found.(127)" is an indication you have a corrupt system file, specifically *Shutdown.exe*, which suggests running SFC/DISM to fix the corruption would be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: From a PS command prompt, what happens if you run `Restart-Computer` you can look at the help to initiate a remote shutdown as well.

Comment: @John I completed all 3 commands. Ironically, it says I won't see the effects until my next reboot, which still doesn't work (yet). [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Gx2DTvS.png)

Comment: Yes, you do have to restart, or,  shut down and start up.  DISM fixes things but does not (in the running screen) say what.

Comment: @HelpingHand [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/hlhUGGZ.png)

Comment: @LonnieBest - [The advice to use the command wasn't complete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-7).  `Restart-Computer` absolutely is a PowerShell command though.  However, I can already tell you, it's just a PowerShell module that initiates `Shutdown.exe`.  So you will still need to force a restart, to see if the corruption that was fixed, resolves the problem.

Comment: (continued)...."Restart-Computer uses the Win32Shutdown method of the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Win32_OperatingSystem class. This method requires the SeShutdownPrivilege privilege be enabled for the user account used to restart the machine."

Comment: It is ridiculous that there is no command that will restart this computer. I was even able to locate the shutdown.exe file and the command still doesn't work: `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -r -f` In Linux, if you type `reboot` you're done.

Comment: @LonnieBest - You are running the correct command.  You just ran into a system corruption issue that involves the file responsible for it, which is the reason, even a reboot through the start menu isn’t possible

Comment: I saw your most recent comment today. What is left now is trying a Repair Install (Microsoft Media Creation Link) or back it up and reinstall Windows .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** The first step is to run DISM / SFC from an Admin Command Prompt. Run in order:

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW . Attempt to restart or shut down and start up.

**(2)** If the above fails to work, then use either a Repair Install (Microsoft Media Creation Link) or back it up and reinstall Windows.